# Was de Staël's On Literature Considered in Its Relations with Social Institutions influenced by late-18th-century German romantics?

Tags: french-language, theory, definition-of-literature, germaine-de-stael, on-literature-considered

In an answer to the question [Can formal essays be considered as a literature in strict sense?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/17593/2191), I wrote that our current definition of literature

> reflects a concept of literature that originated in early 19th-century romanticism and that is restricted to imaginative writing. Culler cites Madame de Staël's *On Literature Considered in Its Relations with Social Institutions*, published in 1800, as an influential source of this conception, even though its roots go back to late-18th-century German romantics.

This raises another question, namely

> whether Germaine de Staël was influenced by those German romantics *before* 1800. During her [exile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germaine_de_Sta%C3%ABl#German_travels) she lived in Germany for some time and "travelled on to Berlin, where she made the acquaintance of August Schlegel who was lecturing there on literature", but that was after 1800.

So that is what I am asking now: is there any evidence for an influence of late-18th-century German romantic concepts of literature on de Staël's *On Literature Considered in Its Relations with Social Institutions*?